# Windows Server: Can't set static IP address

Tags: windows, networking, ip

This is on a Windows Server 2022 VM that I am trying to set up as an Active Directory domain controller. After configuring AD, I added a network interface "Ethernet 2", whose IP address I am trying to set.
What am I doing wrong? Where would I find clues?

On the command line, *netsh* doesn't complain, but the address is not set:

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator> netsh interface ipv4 set address "ethernet 2" static address=10.100.100.1 mask=255.255.255.0

PS C:\Users\Administrator> netsh interface ipv4 show config "ethernet 2"

Configuration for interface "Ethernet 2"
    DHCP enabled:                         No
    InterfaceMetric:                      25
    Statically Configured DNS Servers:    None
    Register with which suffix:           Primary only
    Statically Configured WINS Servers:   None
```

Strangely, the GUI shows the address.
[image]

However, attempts to ping it on the same computer fail.

**It turns out that I can set an address**, e.g. 10.100.100.2. However, 10.100.100.1 doesn't work. While I understand that this is normally a gateway's address, I was not aware that servers refuse the first address in a subnet.

Comment: 1) Are you attempting to ping it from the same subnet? 2) Do your server's firewall rules allow inbound pings (ICMP Echo requests)?

Comment: `attempts to ping it on the same computer` how are yo doing this ... `fail` with what error

Comment: I run *ping* on the same computer where I try to configure the network interface. In other words, the computer pings itself. The error is "*Request timed out.*". I also turned the firewall off for all networks; no change. Pings to the address of the other interface named *Ethernet* succeed. I believe that the interface has no address, even though the GUI claims it has.

Comment: *route print* shows that no route to this address exists.

Comment: Set the VM App tp Bridged networking, restart the Server Guest and then you should be able to establish a static IP for the guest.

Comment: Thanks John. The VM runs on a Debian computer and is connected to an isolated network implemented by a Linuxbridge. I am not sure if you call that a bridged network, but that is what I need. There are other VMs on the same isolated network which have no trouble setting the address.

Comment: I have more information and added an edit. I guess the problem is not that burning anymore, though I am still scratching my head.